How to use images in Components within TypeScript and React just by passing the path?
I am currently facing the problem of loading images into my Card Component just by passing the path:
My Card component looks as follows:
interface CardProps {
    imageLink: string;
    alt: string;
    title: string;
    text: string;
  }


const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <img className="card-image" src={props.imageLink} alt={props.alt}></img>
            <h2 className="card-title">{props.title}</h2>
            <p className="card-text">{props.text}</p>
        </div>
    );
}



export default Card

So I would like the Card Component to show the image I am passing when using it in the App.tsx
import Header from "./Header.tsx";
import Footer from "./Footer.tsx";
import Card from "./Card.tsx";
import Button from "./Button.tsx";

function App() {


  return(
    <>
    <Header/>
    <Card imageLink="./assets/testLogo.png" alt="Test" title="Test" text="Test"/>
    <Button/>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App

Obviously I do not want to import every file I am going to use in the future. Everything works so far, just the image is not loading properly
Some people use "require" but its not included in TypeScript

I found a perfect solution:

Create a "utils" folder inside your project folder
Create "image-utils.ts" or js if you use JavaScript.
Code the following:

function getImageURL(name: String) {
    return new URL(`../assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
}
export {getImageURL};


In your App you then import it, and just call it when passing the file name

import { getImageURL } from "./utils/image-util.ts";

function App() {


  return(
    <>
    <Header/>
    <Card imageLink={getImageURL("testLogo.png")} alt="Test Logo" title="Test Title" text="Test text"/>
    <Button/>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App


Thats it! No require, no webpack :)

Credit go to tapaScript
